# Select options text as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multiple-select

Suppose, we have multiple select.

We want to get text from selected values;

I try to get them like :

```
var rr = $('.selectpicker').find('option:selected').text();
```

but this return just string. 
I need this text values like array.

Some example : http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `array`. it cannot directly display as array. You have to iterate one by one selected option and push it to `jQuery` array.

```
$('#f1').click(function(){    
   var rr = []; 
   $('.selectpicker :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
        rr[i] = $(selected).text(); 
    });
    alert(rr);
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/9/)**